# How can I make a Winforms datagridview expand column widths to fit content?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need my columns to be only as big as the largest value in that column.

Is there a setting somewhere I can set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the [`AutoSizeColumnsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) property to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells` (or the appropriate value for you).  Or call [`AutoResizeColumns()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumns.aspx) to resize the columns as you need it.